# Java mongodb connecion to remote server

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have amazon ec2 windows instance running, and i have associated elastic ip to it. I have installed mongoDB on this instance. When i try to connect to this remote mongodb database using java it gives me following error:

> com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector initDirectConnection WARNING: Exception
>   executing isMaster command on /54.200.155.174:27017
>   java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/54.200.155.174:27017]
>   bc:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out.

Mongodb version used is 2.0.7 and this is my connection code:

```
try
    {
        Mongo mongo=new Mongo("54.200.155.174",27017);
        DB db=mongo.getDB("mydb");
        DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("users");
        DBCursor cursor=coll.find();
        DBObject db1;

        while(cursor.hasNext())
        {
            db1=cursor.next();
            Object o=db1.get("email_id");
            System.out.println("email:"+o.toString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Check the AWS security groups, is application and mongo in same system? is 27017 open for read/write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a network issue. Maybe there is some firewall? 
Check if you can `telnet` to this ip and port. Or check if you can `ping` it.

Comment: I have disabled the firewall and i am able to ping it.

Comment: What are you getting with: telnet 54.200.155.174 27017